# How can I change a TextView's font programmatically in a RemoteView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is there a way to programmatically change the font family of a textview in a widget? I just want to use the system fonts (Roboto Thin, Condensed, etc.), not any custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use library of RoboFont, below is the example how I used the library for textview.

```
<com.eevoskos.robotoviews.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/table_row_header"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/table_row_header"
                android:text="Product"
                app:typeface="condensed_bold" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. I meant how can I change the font programatically. I'd like the user to be able to choose which font they'd like and then select the font according to their choice. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: How to give option for that I have no Idea, but if you want to use custom font for user. you can do same thing for edit text also.